# Google chrome developer tools messed up

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-developer-toolbar

I am having an issue with the google chrome developer tools, they have become unusable, I don't think I have done anything to cause this. Any ideas how I can fix it?

Google Chrome 26.0.1410.43 on Ubuntu 12.10

I doubt this is the most appropriate place to ask this, but I don't know where else I can?

[image: Messed up - Google Chrome Developer tools]

Extensions installed:

- Adblock Plus 1.4
- Any.DO 1.0.2.5
- Apt-linker 1.2.2
- betterChrome - Browse 15% faster 1.0.8
- Chromify-OSD 2.3.0
- Dilandau 1.1.2
- Edit This Cookie 1.2.1
- FB unseen 0.1.4
- FVD Video Downloader 5.0.3
- Google Dictionary (by Google) 3.0.17
- Google Docs 0.5
- Google Quick Scroll 2
- InvisibleHand 3.8.31
- JSONView 0.0.32
- MightyText - Send/Receive SMS Text Messages 9.4
- Novell Moonlight 3.99.0.3
- Outlook.com Notifier 0.1
- Pendule 1.0.0
- Postman - REST Client 0.8.0.4
- Rapportive 1.4.1
- Search by Image (by Google) 1.4.2
- Straight Search 1.17.8
- Tampermonkey 2.12.3124.133
- Wappalyzer 2.20
- Webpage & WebCam Screenshot 7.3.2
- XML Tree 1.9.2.1

Comment: What, if any, client side scripts are you running?

Comment: In what way are they unusable?

Comment: @dcd018, I added the list of extensions I have installed, but I don't think it was any of those, as uninstalling, and then reinstalling (which keeps the extensions/user settings etc) fixed it?!? rebooting had not fixed it, so no idea...

Comment: @ExplosionPills Notice in the screenshot above, the overlapping and jumbled elements list?

Comment: I heard similar reports on the google-chrome-developer-tools Google group. The fix there was restart Chrome with a new profile. Here's one way to do this:

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059